# mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 138520 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on csv file upload.
When I upload heavy files(8mb) it could not process and show the url color red into firebug.
When I checked for error into error log file it shows

```
error -> mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 138520 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072).
```

in my `phpinfo` I have increase all file attributes those we need to change.
I am not getting what is the problem and where I need to change for fcgid max length?

Answer (score 6):

The setting you want to change to get rid of that error is called  [FcgidMaxRequestLen](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) and can be set as a normal Apache configuration directive (depending on your OS, but normally in httpd.conf/apache2.conf)

EDIT: I was originally saying that the directive works in htaccess, but [it seems I was remembering wrong](https://serverfault.com/questions/269789/how-config-for-mod-fcgid-apache-modules) and it can only be used in server config and virtual host context.

Comment: thanks for yor reply.Can you please tell me how i can write for it into htaccess file?when i am trying to write for it into htaccess it stop the website and shows 500 interanl server error.

Comment: @user1523311 Added a correction to the answer, I was sure I used it in .htaccess at one time, but it seems I wasn't remembering correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This link explains how to:

http://binaryone.com.au/how-to-fix-mod_fcgid-http-request-length-131619-so-far-exceeds-maxrequestlen-131072-error-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-linux/

If you have vps host with SSH (like putty) with root access you can change the setting (like with vi editor). And restart apache.

Comment: It's better here to outline a solution instead of just linking. Like this (too much for an edit, but feel free to add it to your answer, I'll delete my comment then):

Your 131 kB MaxRequestLen value means you suffer from the too low default on Ubuntu 12.04 up to (at least) 13.10. A solution is: (1) Add the line `FcgidMaxRequestLen 16777216` to file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf` in section `<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>`. Set to whatever data amount you want to allow (here 16 MiB). (2) Also adapt `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini to at least this value. (3) Do a `service apache2 reload`.