# AJAX Jquery is not able to call PHP backend with Multipart/form data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mod-fcgid

I want to send form data to the backend PHP via Ajax JQuery call but it is not able to call the PHP controller class function. Giving me Internal 500 error.
The code is as follows:

HTML

```html
<form class="montform" id="reused_form1" enctype="multipart/form-data"; >
    {{ csrf_field() }}
         ...
    ...
    ...
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Upload Images: 5mb max size</label>

            <p class="file">
                <input name="image" type="file" id="file" class="feedback-input">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    ....
</form>
```

JS code

```js
$(function() {

    $("#reused_form1 input,#reused_form1 select").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour

        var formobj = $form[0];
        var formd = new FormData(formobj);
            
            $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
            $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
            $.ajax({
                url: '/custom-template',
                type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: formd,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                ....
                },
                error: function(response) {
                ....
                },
                complete: function() {
                ....
                }
});
```

Web.php

```php
Route::post('/custom-template', [EmailController::class, 'customTemplate'])->middleware('web');
```

EmailController.php

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\SendMail;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function customTemplate(Request $req)
    {
        echo("im in controller\n");
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have checked the php config it has  upload_max_filesize = 10M and post_max_size = 8M
The file I upload is of 289KB

The Request header looks like this:

> Accept: multipart/form-data
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Length: 291087

I expect to see "im in controller" in the network response.

I am able to see the result when I upload a pdf. But it does not work with PNG or JPG format.

I also checked the error.log for the site
This is what it logs

```
 mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 133937 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066196/2518525) might be useful, it seems to be an Apache directive (`FcgidMaxRequestLen`) that you need to change.

Comment: Please provide the Error Details.